# HTC Desire 310 boot loop after root

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, htc-desire, unbricking

I just rooted my htc desire 310, out of curiousity. Then I rebooted, and found the phone stuck in a boot loop. I followed [this guide](http://androidsdna.com/how-to-root-htc-desire-310-singledual-sim-install-cwm-recovery/). How to recover ?

Comment: Is it stuck in boot loop or boot screen? Did you flash CWM as instructed in that guide?

Comment: @Firelord It shows the boot screen then turns black then vibrates and shows it again, in a loop. No, I didn't.